# Приложение падает при запуске на реальном устройстве (с arm64)

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

Недавно решил создать приложение для iOS с использованием языка C. Теперь у меня имеется следующий код:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <objc/message.h>

extern void UIApplicationMain(int, ...);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Class autoreleasePoolClass = objc_getClass("NSAutoreleasePool");
    id autoreleasePool = objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(autoreleasePoolClass, sel_registerName("alloc")), sel_registerName("init"));
    UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, CFSTR("AppDelegate"));
    objc_msgSend(autoreleasePool, sel_registerName("drain"));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

В другом файле определена следующая функция:

```
__attribute__((constructor))
void initAppDel() {

    AppDelClass = objc_allocateClassPair((Class) objc_getClass("UIResponder"), "AppDelegate", 0);
    objc_registerClassPair(AppDelClass);
}
```

В симуляторе ОС данный код выполняется без проблем. Однако если я его же запускаю на реальном устройстве, приложение сразу падает. Могу лишь предположить, что дело всё в том что запускаю на arm64-устройстве и я что-то вызываю не так. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким раньше (я понимаю что столь необычными извращениями увлекаются немногие)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё решилось довольно-таки просто и скорее всего дело было в переходе с 32 бит на 64. Для того что использовать функцию `UIApplicationMain` без подключения `UIKit` в явном виде через директиву `import` (потому что планировалась минимизировать присутствие Objective-C в проекте) использовалась следующая строчка:

```
extern void UIApplicationMain(int, ...);
```

Однако я решил указать более точно аргументы данной функции и получилась следующее:

```
extern void UIApplicationMain(int, char**, void*, void*);
```

Теперь аргументы передаются в данную функцию корректно (ибо компилятор теперь знает сколько байт занимают её аргументы) и приложение не падает. Не уверен, что хоть кто-то ещё столкнётся в подобными проблемами, но на всякий случай решение я оставлю.